# Objective-C: Casting method to button without using NIB file?

Tags: objective-c, button, action

I am trying to use some action when I click button in navigation controller. But I created this navigation controller and navigation item with coding. And I know how cast in NIB button with action but. How can I do this with coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the action of any control, send it a `-setAction:` message.